# GWT servlets not called at all

Tags: gwt, jetty

I have ported GWT basic Hello World application to jetty-maven-plugin based app.

Everything goes fine, gwt convert client side classes to Javascript and application run properly in dev mode but no response for server side servlet. I do not get any error or exception.

Any idea what is going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Its just sample application generated from Eclipse and ported to jetty-maven-mortbay plugin. When I click send button , no response at all. Is there any procedure to debug. Client side code e.g validateion run ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information to gave 100% answer. But be sure to check:

- Server log output (could be some exception there)
- If there are no exceptions on server side open console in Firebug or Google Dev Tools and load the page in browser. Probably there will be 404 not found errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your servlet is correctly defined in : war->WEB-INF->web.xml.
Definition of servlet is:

I'm sorry but I can't put code example. I don't understand why.
Anna